# What should i change in my code so that when i point on the menu , the hover just covers all the nav bar

Tags: html, css, header, nav

```css
body {
 background: gray;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
}

header {
 background:black;
 height:auto;
 width:100%;
 float:left;
}

header nav {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
header nav ul{
 list-style:none;
 height:auto;
 width:40%;
 float:right;
}

header nav ul li:hover{
 background-color:lime;
 border-radius:5px;
}


header nav ul li{
 color:white;
 float:left;
 margin-left:5%;
 padding:10px 15px;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="header.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 
</body>
</html>
```

i want to make my hover effect background look like the same in picture

[image: Screenshot]

i tried editing my code , but it just highlights the text area but not the height of full header. the image posted has also been coded by me , but unable to find the error.

Comment: Can you please post your code? May be you have written hover for element within <li>. It would be helpful to track the issue if you post your code

Comment: posted the code :) it was a hard time figuring how to post a question here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ul>` tag has a default margin, you can override this in the CSS with `margin: 0`. This will make the `li:hover` the full height of the `<ul>`.

```
header nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    height:auto;
    width:70%;
    float:right;
  margin: 0;
}
```

The default margin is 16px, if you want to preserve the look, add this to the `<li>` padding: `padding:26px 15px;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/pjpwea/cn12hjwt/1/

Answer (score 0):

A small change in ul and li

```
header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: auto;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
    margin: 0; // added
}

header nav ul li {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding: 16px 15px; //added
}
```

Please find code snippet

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}

header {
  background:black;
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}

header nav {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
header nav ul{
  list-style:none;
  height:auto;
  width:40%;
  float:right;
  margin: 0;
}

header nav ul li:hover{
  background-color:lime;
  border-radius:5px;
}


header nav ul li{
  color:white;
  float:left;
  margin-left:5%;
  padding:26px 15px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="sample.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much :) by default the browser creates margin ? and to clear we have to use it. just only for header or any other tags also. ?

Comment: Default styles will be present for few tags. It is always better to have reset.css which contains code that removes default styles added for tags

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/jnpvxu9r/1/

```
header nav ul{
  margin: 0px; margin-left: 20px; padding: 0px;
    list-style:none;
    height:auto;
}

header nav ul li:hover{
    background-color:lime;
}


header nav ul li{
    color:white;
    float:left;
    padding:10px 15px;
  border-radius: 0px;

}
```